# Associating orders with products and customers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm thinking of a schema where a user can add a product to his order list, and that order will have a status, comment, etc. Multiple users can have multiple orders. Each order has one product in it. What would be the preferable way to go?

```
class User
  has_many :orders
end

class Order
  has_one :product
end

class Product
  belongs_to :category
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
end
```

or should I consider going with has_many :through? Plus, the has_one association kind of conflicts with habtm association the Product model has, or is it OK to use it like that? Thanks!

UPD1: After a bunch of experiment I went with following:

```
class Order
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :orders
end

class User
  has_many :orders
end
```

although everything works solid for now, I would love to hear any comments or recomendations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to go about it would be:

```
class User
   has_many :orders
   has_many :products, through: :orders
end

class Order
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :orders
  has_many :users, through: :orders
end
```

More information about associations can be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: this was my first guess, and it seemed correct at first, but the user does not have products. And the Products do not belong to the User.

Comment: The user _can_ have products and products _can_ have users using the answer I've given. `@user.products` will return every product that the user has ordered, and `@product.users` will return every user that has ordered that product. The `has_many :through` association is its own type of association. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: sorry, but that is not the answer I was looking for

Comment: after 2 days of research I now have to admit that you are right. This type of associating works great for me, but I would like to point out why for people who might have the same question: when associated through a third middle-model, it is easy to access objects both ways, so, for example, I can easily check which users have pending orders with certain products

Comment: I'm glad I could help Denis! Thanks for the change of heart.